# Can computer take ip from dhcp without join at domain?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

im new here

my question is :

Can computer take ip from dhcp without join at domain?

i have windows server 2012 (AD-DNS-DHCP) (Domain) and all computers at workgroup ... soooo 
Can computer take ip from dhcp without join at domain?

thanx..

Comment: `Can computer take ip from dhcp without join at domain?` - Yes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Microsoft DHCP Server will give out IP addresses to all systems.

However, you will need a Client Access License for each device that uses the DHCP server, because Microsoft. This is not technically enforced, but the license text is unambiguous. See also [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/597806-dhcp-on-windows-server-what-is-this-licensing-madness) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2x4ift/ms_licensing_question_cal_for_every_dhcp_user/).

Thus, you might want to look into different ways to provide DHCP (and DNS) service.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what others have said, you don’t need to join the domain to get a DHCP address. Think about how DHCP works: how would the DHCP server know your computer was a valid member of the domain at the point DHCP is negotiating IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. DHCP is a protocol that is not dependent on Active Directory.